# How to use CSS3 Media Query effectively?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm a little bit confuse when using Media query for responsive web design.
Actually, I'm new to it and I also want to ask that: is it necessary to add media query every single time you have a CSS error when shrinking down the web browser? I used to do it and my css had like a lot of media queries in it!

Answer (score 2):

You should use media queries when you want to specify different style for a particular height/width of the screen.

Media queries can also be used to change layout of a page depending on the orientation of the browser.

[Please use this link to find out more..](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

[7 Practices for Effective Media Queries](http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/)

Comment: Is it good to have lots of media queries in my css file (when not using any css framework)?

Answer (score 0):

Do use media query to design layout for desktop version. You should always think for mobile first layout then use media query to decide how should it look like in desktop version of site.